# How to build an npm package so it is able to be imported/required

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have built an npm package and published it onto NPM.

When i `npm install <my-package>` and then `import MyPackage from "@Acme/MyPackage";` into react i get the following error.

Module not found: Can't resolve @Acme/MyPackage

Is this becasue of how i have setup my sdk package. You can find the webpack config i use to build it below.

Btw this works if i import the script tag directly in the header, but how can i import it like this without specifically defining the script tag in the header?

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
// const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'my-package.min.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        library: 'MyPackage'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        console: false,
        global: true,
        process: true,
        __filename: 'mock',
        __dirname: 'mock',
        Buffer: true,
        setImmediate: true,
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'

        // See "Other node core libraries" for additional options.
    },
    plugins: [
        // new UglifyJSPlugin({ sourceMap: true }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            { from: 'test/index.html', to: '' }
        ]),
    ],
};
```

Comment: Your package is on a private NPM registry @Acme is that correct? And it's there in the `node_modules` folder?

Comment: @jerrylow no the Acme is a namespace and yes i can see the min.js file within node_modules

Comment: Are you able to share the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `import` doesn't know where to import the package from but since it's already in your `node_modules` folder I'm going to guess that either you don't have an `index.js` file or you haven't defined your main entry file for you package.

Every NPM package will look for an `index.js` file but if you have want to rename it you can actually define it in your `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "yourpackage",
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "main": "another-name.min.js",
}
```

Comment: Btw I think this is the issue but if it's not you'll have to resolve the path to your package in webpack https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: thank you after pointing main to my dist file that webpack outputs it worked.