# An issue with creating an npm package: 'Cannot find module ...'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I ​recently published an npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/splashup-widget.

I tried to install it in a 'create-react-app' sample app, but I got an error `Cannot find module 'splashup-widget'`

this is the webpack config:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('build'),
        filename: 'index.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        react: "react"
      }
}
```

This is a React code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Quiz from 'splashup-widget'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <Quiz />
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I checked this question: [How to build an npm package so it is able to be imported/required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674298/how-to-build-an-npm-package-so-it-is-able-to-be-imported-required)
but it seems that it's not my case, since both entry and output filenames are 'index.js'.

Would greatly appreciate any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `main` field in your package's `package.json` is incorrect; you should change it from `index.js` to `build/index.js`.